# textarea print a two char when press a single key on keypressup event

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using google virtual keybord and set on the textarea.
When I write something on textarea so in a textarea they print two character one was uppercase and second was lowercase.

I write a JavaScript function for textarea in which after "." - dot those character is make it automatically capital Alphabet.

How I can remove a one character and textarea print just only one character? Because when I press single key they print two character.
this function iam using for uppercase after the "." dot and set up keypress event on textarea.

```
function caps(e, textarea, value){
    //debugger;
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    var str=value.trim();
    str=str.charAt(str.length-1);

    if((str=="." || value.length==0) && (unicode>=97 && unicode<=122)){
        textarea.value=textarea.value+String.fromCharCode(unicode).toUpperCase();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems you just need to remove the last character before adding the new one. Therefore something like this should work (it's untested though).

```
if((str=="." || value.length==0) && (unicode>=97 && unicode<=122)){
    /*remove last character before adding new one*/
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.value.length - 1);
    textarea.value=textarea.value+String.fromCharCode(unicode).toUpperCase();
    return false;
}
```

Although, depending on how this function is being called, you may be able to prevent the character being printed in the first place.

---

Sorry, realised you did say in the question title that it's the keypress event. In which case, `e.preventDefault` is your friend as shown in another answer. You can just replace your `return false` with it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the default behaviour of an event, you can use `e.preventDefault();`. So something like

```
function caps(e, textarea, value){
    //debugger;
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode; //my keyboard threw out ascii..

    var str=value.trim();
    str=str.charAt(str.length-1);
    if(str=="." || value.length==0){

      textarea.value=textarea.value+String.fromCharCode(unicode).toUpperCase();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}


input.addEventListener("keypress",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==8) return true
     caps(e,input,input.value)

},false)
```

You could use `return false`, but you need to do something like

```
input.onkeypress=function(){
    if(e.keyCode==8) return true
    return caps(e,input,input.value); //pass false from caps too event
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/LSH6D/)